# export to excel file from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export

I want to export data to excel file(Generate excel file and prompt download using Response).
I have a DataSet.I want to export using my own formatting.Like adding a logo. Changing some colums background color. Making some rows bold.

Problems:

1. I tried to use xml spreadsheet but I found no way to insert image.And also when opening a file there was a warning message(because it is not in binary format rather in xml format)
2. I also tried excellibrary.But i could not use background color for any cell.I found that it is an issue of excellibrary which is not solved yet.

So is there an efficient way I can export data(of course it should be free).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with different ways - for example via HTML-Export... for some in-depth information regarding the HTML approach to creating Excel files with sample code see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx

Also checkout the official documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

Other options to create Excel files:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx

IF you need more like rendering, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) (commercial), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) (commercial) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) (commercial) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this. May be, this will help you:

```
System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
dg.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library (EDIT: will be 14 now actually)

It has been a while since I used it but it is standard in Visual Studio (I think) and the Microsoft library for dealing with Office documents.

Comment: That is Interop and NOT supported by MS in ASP.NET (although it sometimes "works")

Comment: Well of course its interop, MS Office isnt built on .NET (yet anyway). But you can access it via ASP.NET depending on the machine you are running it on. If you have shared hosting it most likely won't work. But it will if you have a virtual or dedicated machine and install office on it.

Comment: This is not my question... the OP wrote "Generate excel file and prompt download using Response" which is a hint at ASP.NET or at least a web application...